# Oracle SQL - Selecting column without knowing column name

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to select the value of the second column using something like an index or column position if i dont know the name of the column?

```
Select col(2) FROM (
    Select 'a', 'b',' c', 'd' from dual
)
```

Comment: No, although you can use that syntax in an `order by` statement.

Comment: For your example you could alias the columns in the subquery; `'b' as col2` etc. - so you'd have a known name rather than an auto-generated name from the value. I assume your actual use case is more involved; though I can't imagine why you'd want or need to be able to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it possible?  Sure.  You could write a PL/SQL block that used `dbms_sql` to open a cursor using the actual query against `dual`, describe the results, bind a variable to whatever you find the second column to be, fetch from the cursor, and then loop.  That would be a terribly involved and generally rather painful process but it could be done.

The SQL language does not define a way to do this in a static SQL statement and Oracle does not provide an extension that would allow this.  I'd be rather concerned about the underlying problem that you're trying to solve, though, if you somehow know that you want the second column but don't know what that column represents.  That's not something that makes a lot of sense in a relational database.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'dual'
```

not sure if this is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the name, just give it a nice name ;).

```
Select b FROM (
    Select 'a', 'b' as b, 'c', 'd' from dual
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in case when you know number of columns in the subquery:

```
SELECT COL2 FROM (
  SELECT NULL COL1, NULL COL2, NULL COL3, NULL COL4 
  UNION ALL 
  select 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' from dual
) 
WHERE COL2 IS NOT NULL;
```

There are limitations:

- query is hard to read and understand
- you should know number of columns
- value should not be NULL
- not recommended for production use

Answer (score 0):

As Justin Cave said, there is no builtin SQL way to get the unknown column names but can be done by PL/SQL. Here is an Example that demonstrate the way Justin said.

```
declare
  cur             INTEGER;
  tab_description DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
  col_num         NUMBER;
begin
  --open a cursor
  cur := dbms_sql.OPEN_CURSOR;
  --parse your query
  dbms_sql.PARSE(cur, 'select 1 a, 2 b, 3 c from dual', DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
  --now let dbms_sql describe your columns (col_num and tab_description are OUT Parameter)
  dbms_sql.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(cur, col_num, tab_description);
  --close the cursor
  dbms_sql.CLOSE_CURSOR(cur);
  
  --number of columns in your Query
  dbms_output.put_line(col_num);
  
  --loop and print the column names
  for i in 1..col_num loop
    dbms_output.put_line(tab_description(i).col_name);
  end loop;
end;
```

You can create your own PL/SQL Function to get the information you need in your queries.
For more information, I would suggest to have a look in Oracle Docu.